# Tips for creating a kid-friendly, secure environment for Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: 12.10

Keep in mind I'm already aware of Edubuntu, Doudou, and other child-friendly Ubuntu operating systems, but I am interested in knowing some of the top tips to lock-down my Ubuntu 12.10 distro for sole-use of my after school program.

Some things I'd like to do but do not know how:

1. Create links on the desktop to visit certain approved webpages, but
   while also having the address bar locked and the history and
   bookmarks locked as well (no way to visit outside websites). I understand this would be the most difficult aspect, especially since I can't directly access my work's router. I can live without internet, but I really would like them to utilize sites like Khan Academy.
2. Create a computer-use timer that could log someone out automatically. (To initiate the clock I would have a giant start button on the desktop.
3. I'm also looking for some suggestions on games/software that are educational and fun:)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try DansGuardian

> DansGuardian is an award winning Open Source web content filter which
>   currently runs on Linux, FreeBSD, OpenBSD, NetBSD, Mac OS X, HP-UX,
>   and Solaris. It filters the actual content of pages based on many
>   methods including phrase matching, PICS filtering and URL filtering.
>   It does not purely filter based on a banned list of sites like lesser
>   totally commercial filters.

To install [**DansGuardian** [image: Install comixcursors-lefthanded]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/dansguardian/)

And for the latest version you can download from [Here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dansguardian/files/).  Its available in .tar.bz2 file.  On instructions of how to install see this [Post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-to-install-a-tar-gz-or-tar-bz2-file).

<sup>Source:[DansGuardian](http://dansguardian.org/)</sup>